# Why bech32 address always starts with bc1q?

Tags: bech32-address

I understand that it starts bc1.

But 'q' is not what I understand. Can someone explain to me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`q` is the Bech32 encoding of the number 0. For a segwit address, as defined in BIP 173, the number immediately following the separator is the witness version. In this case, bc1q, the q means it is a witness v0 address, which is the only type currently used but allows for easy future addition of new versions

Answer (score 4):

Immediately following the human readable part and separator of a bech32 address is the witness version number. For current bech32 addresses, that version number is 0. According to the encoding table [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki#bech32), the value for a 0 byte is `q`. Thus addresses will begin with `bc1q`.

Answer (score 3):

There is of corse BIP173, which explains bc1 for better readability.

More interesting is a [thread in bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2624630.msg26762627#msg26762627), where Greg Maxwell explains details. 
Searching the forum here and bitcointalk for bech32 reveals lots of interesting facts :-)